# How can I get photos to look sharp and save for the web?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, images

I am working in Adobe Illustrator...and old version...version 5. I am importing photos and doing a banner design for a website. Every time my client views it, her comments are the photos are blurry. I agree. It is probably a simple fix. Canyon help?

Comment: Why are you using AI to create a banner design for a website? Isn't PS what you should be working with? AI is basically for vector work while PS does a better job at handling raster.

Comment: @Alin Are you joking? Ai is used heavily for web design. In fact a lot of artwork on the web is vector. It's faster, smaller, and lighter to load than a raster image for many different purposes

Comment: @user105119 Are these raster images or vector images that you are importing into Illustrator?

Comment: @user105119 is your customer complaining about the photo quality being blurry or the banner design being blurry?

Comment: @LateralTerminal , I quote " * I am importing photos... * ", therefore raster. I stand my ground when I say that for this use case, creating a BANNER with photos, not vector as you stated, the best tool is PS.

Comment: @Alin Even if it is raster it is still really common to use Ai for the final template. Especially if everything other than the photo is vector. I'm not debating its efficiency . It's just how a lot of businesses structure their workflow for best or for worse

Comment: @Alin other elements in the Ai document would probably be used as SVG elements. At least thats my assumption

Answer (score 1):

If your client is commenting that the photos are "blurry," this may not be what you think. Perhaps the client is looking at the banner in an enlarged view (not actual size) making the photos' pixels noticeable. If this is the case, you need to talk your client off the ledge. Instruct the client to view the banner in a web browser (FILE > OPEN), not from an email, nor from double clicking on the attachment in an email.